# Hybris Solr Sort

Tags: sorting, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I modified my code to add new solr sort for price.

```
INSERT_UPDATE FieldSolrSort;sort(indexedType(identifier),code)[unique=true];fieldName[unique=true];descending[unique=true];$IndexedType:price;priceValue;true
```

I have currently two solr sort

- Name Ascending
- Name Descending

I added new solr sort for price

- Price Ascending
- Price Descending

But I want my new solr sort to only show when the user has logged in. Anyone know? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1: Import impex to enable price sort option

If you refer any OOTB store(`apparelstore`), you are able to see Price Sort (`price-asc`) option in Impex. I have highlighted Impex below.

### Step 2: Hide from the anonymous user

Don't render Price sort in case of the anonymous user. You can take help of JSTL condition to check that as I mentioned below.

Please Note: Below code is just reference for you, I haven't tested it

### `orderFormPagination.tag`

```
                        <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
                        <%@ taglib prefix="fn"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
                        <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>

                        <c:set var="isLoggedInUser" value="false" />
                        <sec:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_ANONYMOUS">
                            <c:set var="isLoggedInUser" value="true" />
                        </sec:authorize>

                        <select id="sortOptions${top ? '1' : '2'}" name="sort" class="form-control">
                            <option disabled><spring:theme
                                    code="${themeMsgKey}.sortTitle" /></option>
                            <c:forEach items="${searchPageData.sorts}" var="sort">

                                <c:if test="${isLoggedInUser || (!isLoggedInUser && !fn:startsWith(sort.code, 'price'))}">
                                    <option value="${sort.code}"
                                        ${sort.selected? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>
                                        <c:choose>
                                            <c:when test="${not empty sort.name}">
                                        ${sort.name}
                                    </c:when>
                                            <c:otherwise>
                                                <spring:theme code="${themeMsgKey}.sort.${sort.code}" />
                                            </c:otherwise>
                                        </c:choose>
                                    </option>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>
```

---

### Impex

---

Define SolrIndexedProperty

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty ; solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique=true] ; name[unique=true]      ; type(code) ; sortableType(code) ; currency[default=false] ; localized[default=false] ; multiValue[default=false] ; useForSpellchecking[default=false] ; useForAutocomplete[default=false] ; fieldValueProvider                      ; ftsPhraseQuery[default=false] ; ftsPhraseQueryBoost ; ftsQuery[default=false] ; ftsQueryBoost ; ftsFuzzyQuery[default=false] ; ftsFuzzyQueryBoost ; ftsWildcardQuery[default=false] ; ftsWildcardQueryType(code)[default=POSTFIX] ; ftsWildcardQueryBoost ; ftsWildcardQueryMinTermLength
                                  ; $solrIndexedType                         ; name                   ; text       ; sortabletext       ;                         ; true                     ;                           ; true                               ; true                              ;                                         ; true                          ; 100                 ; true                    ; 50            ; true                         ; 25                 ;                                 ;                                             ;                       ;
                                  ; $solrIndexedType                         ; priceValue             ; double     ;                    ; true                    ;                          ;                           ;                                    ;                                   ; productPriceValueProvider               ;                               ;                     ;                         ;               ;                              ;                    ;                                 ;                                             ;                       ;
```

Define the available sorts

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrSort ; &sortRefID ; indexedType(identifier)[unique=true] ; code[unique=true] ; useBoost  
                       ; sortRef3   ; $solrIndexedType                     ; name-asc          ; false   
                       ; sortRef4   ; $solrIndexedType                     ; name-desc         ; false   
                       ; sortRef5   ; $solrIndexedType                     ; price-asc         ; false   
                       ; sortRef6   ; $solrIndexedType                     ; price-desc        ; false
```

Define the sort fields

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrSortField ; sort(indexedType(identifier),code)[unique=true] ; fieldName[unique=true] ; ascending[unique=true]                
                            ; $solrIndexedType:name-asc                       ; name                   ; true                  
                            ; $solrIndexedType:name-desc                      ; name                   ; false                 
                            ; $solrIndexedType:price-asc                      ; priceValue             ; true                  
                            ; $solrIndexedType:price-desc                     ; priceValue             ; false
```

Update sorts option in Indexed type Product

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedType ; identifier[unique=true] ; type(code) ; variant ; sorts(&sortRefID)                                    
                              ; $solrIndexedType        ; Product    ; false   ; sortRef3,sortRef4,sortRef5,sortRef6
```

### Find [detail post here](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/03/in-hybris-how-add-or-update-ootb-sort.html)

---

### If you want to know [how to add custom Sort By Option with custom AttributeComparator?](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/03/in-hybris-how-to-add-custom-sort-by.html)

Comment: ive added already the new solr sorts with the correct function, now i want that only login-user can see the new added solr sort. thanks

Comment: Don't render `Price` option by puting a condition in `JSP/tag`. Check my updated post.

Comment: Even this won't sop anonymous user to sort by price if the user knows the URL because we just hide it from UI. You need to handle it on the server side to restrict it at all.

Comment: does the code in the .tag file only hide the price sort option if it is from an anonymous user?

Comment: yes, you can see the condition `!isLoggedInUser && !fn:startsWith(sort.code, 'price')`

Comment: i have another question, for the .tag file, what language is that? so i can search more about it. it's my first time to encounter this kind of syntax.

Comment: It is  'JSTL'  condition