# How to add Hybris Solr By for Boolean value

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I have a Solr indexed property called **isNewProduct** (boolean) and I want to create a new Solr By option for this attribute. (the products with isNewProduct==true must appear first).

Any hint about how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Have you seen [Hybris Solr Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512571/hybris-solr-sort)? You should be able to follow the same plan for `isNewProduct`.

Comment: I've followed this https://www.helphybris.com/2018/03/how-to-add-custom-sort-by-option-in-hybris.html and It didn't worked

Comment: The link you tried to follow is for custom comparator but here in your case you do not need to write any custom comparator. @MatsLindh pointed correct link. For boolean or string value, you can do it without changing any code. Follow [how to add or update Sort by Options](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/03/how-to-update-short-by-option-hybris.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is run below Impex (change it with your actual values) and you are done.

```
    $lang=en
    $solrIndexedType=YourProductType


    INSERT_UPDATE SolrSort ; indexedType(identifier)[unique=true] ; code[unique=true] ; name[lang=$lang] ; useBoost
                           ; $solrIndexedType                     ; isNewProduct      ; New Product      ;false 

    INSERT_UPDATE SolrSortField ; sort(indexedType(identifier),code)[unique=true] ; fieldName[unique=true] ; ascending[unique=true]
                                ; $solrIndexedType:isNewProduct                   ; isNewProduct           ; true
```

Please note, when we add a new SolrSort, Hybris internally added its reference to `SolrIndexedType` in `sorts` field so that you can see that option on the storefront. But if your SolrSort value is missing, you can always verify and correct it using back-office/Impex.

Something like below

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedType ; identifier[unique=true] ; sorts(code)                                    
                              ; $solrIndexedType        ; SolrSortCode1,SolrSortCode2,isNewProduct
```

Comment: Please , check this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497641/how-to-sort-with-a-nested-filter-in-hybris-solr