# How to sort with a "nested" filter in Hybris Solr

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

Relationed to this post [How to add Hybris Solr By for Boolean value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479808/how-to-add-hybris-solr-by-for-boolean-value/57490216)

I need to add a kind of "nested filter": when I filter with my boolean atribute isNewProduct , inside this sort , I want to sort by relevance (number indexed property) for example :

I have this products:

```
Product A : isNewProduct = true , relevance = 100;
Product B : isNewProduct = false , relevance = 50;
Product C : isNewProduct = true , relevance = 300;
Product D : isNewProduct = false , relevance = 40;
```

When I filter by isNewProduct, the result must be :

```
Product C > Product A > Product B > Product D.
```

Is possible to make an ordenation inside another ordenation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you want the second field as a score. Try like this

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrSortField ; sort(indexedType(identifier),code)[unique=true] ; fieldName[unique=true] ; ascending[unique=true]
                                ; $solrIndexedType:isNewProduct                   ; isNewProduct       ; true 
                                ; $solrIndexedType:isNewProduct                   ; score              ; false
```

Comment: The second value isn't suposed to override the first?

Comment: No, Because `sort` and `fieldName` combination is unique. So it won't override the first. Just try it out.

Comment: Can you check this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58412355/hybris-mediamodel-how-to-get-bytes